# Why does the Quartz misfireThreshold not work?

Tags: java, quartz

Setting :-

quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=300000 // 5 minutes

```
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.start();

        JobDetail cronJob = newJob().ofType(MyJob.class)
                .storeDurably()
                .withIdentity("CRON_JOB")
                .build();

        CronTrigger cronTrigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("CRON_TRIGGER")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 * * ? * *")
                        .withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
                .startAt(new Date())
                .forJob(cronJob)
                .build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(cronJob, cronTrigger);

        // don't shutdown immediately.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        
        scheduler.shutdown();
```

I'm expecting 5 minutes worth of non misfired ( within threshold ) jobs to fire when i start the scheduler back up. This doesn't happen. The instruction withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing otherwise works. ie. it fires a job the next minute after start up, and every minute thereafter. But the threshold is supposed to treat jobs as non misfired jobs, and run them on start up. It doesn't work